# В гугл таблицах при нажатии чек бокса сохранить в строке формулы как значения

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

В гугл таблице столбцы А-О считаются формулами. А в столбце P стоит чек бокс. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на чек бокс (равен ИСТИНА) формулы в строке сохранялись как значения (c A до P). Прошу помочь с макросом.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [простой триггер onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) для реакции скрипта на изменения пользователем данных в колонке P. В итоге код будет примерно такой:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() != 16) return;  // 16-я я колонка - это P
  if (e.value == 'TRUE') {
    var rowRange = e.range.offset(0, -15, 1, 15);
    // Извлекаем значения из колонок A:O ряда (без формул)
    // и сразу же записываем их обратно на то же место
    rowRange.setValues(rowRange.getValues());
  }
}
```